# $\{b \in \mathbb{R}: h^*(b)>c\}$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ , $h^*$ being the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

$\textbf{Question}$: Suppose $h: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue measurable. Define $h^*:\mathbb{R}\to [0, \infty]$ with $|h|<\infty$ such that $\displaystyle h^*(b)=\sup_{t>0} \frac{1}{2t}\int_{b-t}^{b+t}|h| \ $.  Prove that $\{b \in \mathbb{R}: h^*(b)>c\}$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ for all $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

$\textbf{Attempt}$: Write $A=\{b \in \mathbb{R}: h^*(b)>c\}$. We are to prove that for any $b\in A$, $\exists \ \epsilon>0$ such that $(b-\epsilon,b+\epsilon)\subset A$ (provided that $A \neq \emptyset)$

By the definition of $h^*$, $\exists \ t_0>0$ such that $h^*(b)\geq \frac{1}{2t_0}\int_{b-t_0}^{b+t_0}|h|>h^*(b)-\delta/3>c$ where $\delta>0$ is such that $h^*(b)-\delta>c$.

Now, $\displaystyle\ h^*(b)+\frac{1}{2t_0}\int_{b+t_0}^{(x+b)+t_0}|h|-\frac{1}{2t_0}\int_{b-t_0}^{(x+b)-t_0}|h|\geq \frac{1}{2t_0}\bigg(\int_{b-t_0}^{b+t_0}|h|+\int_{b+t_0}^{(x+b)+t_0}|h|-\int_{b-t_0}^{(x+b)-t_0}|h|\bigg)=\frac{1}{2t_0}\int_{(x+b)-t_0}^{(x+b)+t_0}|h|$, where $x>0$

Let $\displaystyle\alpha = \sup_{(b+t_0, x+b+t_0)}|h|$ and $\displaystyle\beta=\sup_{(b-t_0, x+b-t_0)}|h|$ (assuming the boundedness of $f$ within a small enough interval).

So, we have $\displaystyle-\frac{x\alpha}{2t_0}\leq\frac{1}{2t_0}\int_{b+t_0}^{(x+b)+t_0}|h|\leq \frac{x\alpha}{2t_0}$ and $\displaystyle-\frac{x\beta}{2t_0}\leq-\displaystyle\frac{1}{2t_0}\int_{b-t_0}^{(x+b)-t_0}|h|$

Thereby, $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2t_0}\int_{(x+b)-t_0}^{(x+b)+t_0}|h|>\ (h^*(b)-\delta/3)+\frac{1}{2t_0}\int_{b+t_0}^{(x+b)+t_0}|h|-\frac{1}{2t_0}\int_{b-t_0}^{(x+b)-t_0}|h|\geq h^*(b)-\delta/3-\frac{x\alpha}{2t_0}-\frac{x\beta}{2t_0}\geq h^*(b)-\delta>c$ , whenever $\displaystyle 0\leq x\leq \frac{2t_0\delta}{3\gamma}$, where $\gamma=\max\{\alpha, \beta\}$

For $-x \ (\text{ here too} \ x>0)$, $\ \displaystyle\frac{1}{2t_0}\int_{(b-x)-t_0}^{(b-x)+t_0}|h|=\frac{1}{2t_0}\int_{b-t_0}^{b+t_0}|h|+\frac{1}{2t_0}\int_{(b-x)-t_0}^{b-t_0}|h|-\frac{1}{2t_0}\int_{(b-x)+t_0}^{b+t_0}|h|\geq h^*(b)-\delta>c$.

We take note of the fact the only the $\textit{supremums}$ of the function change, the length of the intervals remains the same. So, in this case, the bound for which the previous inequality holds, becomes $\displaystyle -\frac{2t_0 \delta}{3\tau}\leq -x <0$, where $\displaystyle\tau=\max\{\sup_{(b-x-t_0,b-t_0)}|h|,\sup_{(b-x+t_0,b+t_0)}|h|\}$ by applying exactly the same procedure.

Therefore, by choosing $\epsilon = \min\{\frac{2t_0\delta}{3\gamma}, \frac{2t_0 \delta}{3\tau}\}$, we observe that $(b-\epsilon,b+\epsilon)\subset A$, as required.

*Verification Requested*.

Comment: You cannot assume the local boundedness of $h$.

Comment: @CiaránÓRaghaillaigh, Assuming $|h|<\infty$, does my "proof" work? I'll make a separate case when $h$ becomes unbounded.

Comment: Local boundedness is a very strong condition. Here it amounts to saying $h$ is bounded on compact subsets, i.e. given $[a,b]$ there exists $M>0$ ($M$ depending on the interval) such that $|h(x)|<M$ for all $x\in [a,b]$

Comment: I am assuming that $h$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$, an even stronger condition (edited question).

Comment: A more natural separation of cases would be whether or not there exists $[a,b]$ such that $\int_a^b |h|=\infty$

Comment: So long as $\int_a^b |h|<\infty$ for all intervals $[a,b]$, then the key is that $h(b,t)=\frac{1}{2t}\int_{b-t}^{b+t}|h|$ is continuous in $(b,t)$, $t\neq 0$